# Can flutter_beacon package be used to make Social Distancing app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ibeacon, beacon, altbeacon, proximitysensor

I am working on social distancing app in flutter. Can I use flutter_beacon package for social distancing?
I have tried the example code from

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon/example

but the screen keeps loading i tried to install in two phones but it doesn't detect any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for two phones to detect each other with BLE beaconing you need them to do two things:

1. Advertise a beacon over BLE
2. Scan for beacons over BLE

But flutter_beacon only does item 2 above.  For item 1, you need another package.  Try beacon_broadcast:

https://pub.dev/packages/beacon_broadcast

You need to do both at once.

If you use these, you can build a social distancing app on Android and iOS, but it will only work on iOS in the foreground as beaconing stops in the background on that platform.

Comment: is there any resource to use both at once i mean to merge those packages.
I merged it but itsn't working

Comment: right now flutter_beacon support broadcast https://github.com/alann-maulana/flutter_beacon/issues/67

Answer (score 1):

flutter_beacon package can be used so that your app can communicate with BLE beacons in near proximity of the device. If your idea of a Social Distancing app includes beacons, yes this package can help you with that. If your idea is to measure distance between 2 people having their mobile devices in the pocket than you need to figure out how to measure distance between 2 mobile devices, not between device and a BLE beacon.